# error while writing ClassName Java in vscode ide

Tags: java

The error is as the pic showed:

[image]

Comment: Try to remove package name. Package name is erroneous

Comment: @SagarGangwal: I see no indication that the package name is the problem - and it matches the directory structure. In what way is it "erroneous"?

Comment: Please include the code and error message as *text* rather than just as a picture. Additionally, please tell us more about your project structure. Where is it trying to write the output to, and does the directory exist?

Comment: @JonSkeet, you are right I removed the package, it got more than one error.

Comment: Can you write other classes ok? Or does every class you try to write give the same error? The class looks fine - perhaps it's a permissions issue preventing your IDE writing class files to your filestore?

Comment: @JonH it showed in every class I have created.

Comment: Ok, so it seems to be a problem with your environment setup then or the way you've configured your project in visual code studio. Have you installed Java, set JAVA_HOME environment variable, etc? Do you have another IDE installed that you could try to create a new project with as an alternative to visual code studio, like intelliJ or Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Could you run it directly? It does not look like a problem with Java.

You can intentionally make a compile error and you can clearly see which provided this error message. Most of it was provided by the Java Language Server so you can find 'Java(xxxxx)' at the end of the error message. But the error message in the picture you have provided does not contains it.

So could you disable all extensions and then just enable Java-related extensions to check the error message still exists or not?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `public class` and make it `class` only. IDE is showing error because You have same class name somewhere in another java file. I don't know why but this issue arise in VSCode. If you run your code using cmd than your code will show no error.